# What's the proper name for these chain structured PGMs?

Tags: time-series, markov-process, hidden-markov-model, state-space-models

I'm trying to find previous work that has dealt with this type of PGMs, but don't know what to call them:

a) "recurrent HMM"? $y_i$ are scalars and $x_i$ are discrete

[image: "recurrent HMM?"]

b) "triangle HMM"? again, $y_i$ are scalars and $x_i$ are discrete

[image]

Comment: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/heaukulani13.pdf
This has a similar model. I don't think there is any special name. These are in the class of general dynamic bayesian networks.

Answer (score 0):

These dependency graphs can represent Pairwise Markov Chains. Similar graphs can be seen in Figure 2 of [this article](http://www-public.imtbs-tsp.eu/~pieczyn/A73.pdf).

In such case, you consider both (X,Y) as the Markovian process and the generalization of classical Markov chains algorithms such as Forward-Backward holds, as shown in http://www-public.imtbs-tsp.eu/~pieczyn/A29.pdf Section 3.